# Why is return type void declared as struct in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, clr

AFAIK `void` means nothing in terms of programming language. So why in .Net framework it is declared as `struct`?

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace System
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Specifies a return value type for a method that does not return a value.
  /// </summary>
  /// <filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
  [ComVisible(true)]
  [Serializable]
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 1)]
  public struct Void
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`System.Void` is effectively a marker type - members like [`MethodInfo.ReturnType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.returntype.aspx) have to have *some* way of representing `void`, and `System.Void` is the way the .NET team chose to do so.

You shouldn't use it like a normal type. It's a workaround, effectively - a little like the [F# `Unit` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483472.aspx), but not as fully integrated into the type system.

Comment: if void was well integrated into .net instead of using as workaround, wouldn't it had gave better performance?

Comment: @AppDeveloper, I don't think it would effect performance at all, it really just controls how functions compile, and if they return a value or not. C# Void functions, or VB Subs just don't return values, so the IL Code for pushing/popping stack values for that is just omitted.

Answer (score 3):

A method descriptor contains a field for the method's return type.  While it would be possible to have that field be `null` for `void` functions, that would require that code which wants to e.g. report the method's return type say something like:

```
string theReturnType = theMethod.ReturnType ? theMethod.ReturnType.ToString() : "null";
```

rather than simply saying:

```
string theReturnType = theMethod.ReturnType.ToString();
```

There are enough cases where code has to do something with the method's return type that having to special-case null in all of them would be a far greater bother than simply having a dummy type "null" which can be returned.

Incidentally, although so far as I know `void` is the only type which is usable for a method return value but no other purpose, there are other cases where it would be useful to have a type which could be used for public return values, but not used in outside storage-location declarations, such as when writing a fluent interface (if outside code could be allowed to access members of `biz.boz(3)`, but could not store the value itself, then in a construct like `biz.boz(3).foo(9).bar(2).build()`, the `foo` method could know that it held the only reference anywhere in the universe to the object returned by `boz(3)`, and would thus be free to either mutate it or return a new instance, at its convenience).